How to handle redirects in ways other than at the frontend stage
I would like to discuss the topic of redirects, specifically focusing on how to handle them at the server level before they reach the frontend. While many web applications rely on frontend redirects, I am interested in exploring alternative approaches and techniques.
Here are some specific aspects I would like to delve into:
Types of Redirects: What are the different types of redirects (e.g., 301, 302, 307), and how do they differ in terms of server implementation?
Server-Side Implementation: What are the best practices for implementing redirects at the server level? Are there any preferences between servers, such as Apache and Nginx, regarding redirects?
Managing Redirects in APIs: How can redirects be managed within APIs? What are the best practices for implementing redirects in RESTful or GraphQL services?
Microservices Challenges: What challenges do we face regarding redirects in a microservices architecture? Are there established approaches for centralizing redirect management in such systems?
Security and Performance: What are the potential security risks associated with redirects, such as open redirects, and how can they be mitigated? What techniques can improve redirect performance at the server level?
Analysis and Monitoring: What tools are available for monitoring and analyzing redirects? How can we assess the effectiveness of redirects in terms of user experience?
I would appreciate any suggestions, best practices, and experiences that can help me better understand this topic!
Thank you in advance for your help!
I spoke with my developer colleagues, but they are also unaware of any other possibilities.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
